# Issue with using array pointers (C)

Tags: c

I am writing a program that is meant to read in two arrays and find the difference between the two (elements found in set A but not in set B).

The sets are stored using arrays of 1s and 0s (1s for elements that exist and 0s for elements that don't). I have the following code written and can't seem to understand why I am getting these warnings

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
             if(p==1 && q==0)
                 ^
 warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
                 set_difference = 1;
```

I have the following code written. It will not return a value, either.

```
#define N 10

void find_set_difference(int *set_a, int *set_b, int n, int *set_difference);  

int main(void)
{
    int i, k;
    int n;

    printf("Enter the number of elements in set A: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    int a[n];

    printf("Enter the elements in set A: \n"); 

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[k]);
        a[k] = 1;
    }

    printf("Enter the number of elements in set B: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int b[n];

    printf("Enter the elements in set B: \n"); 

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &b[k]);
        b[k] = 1;
    }

    int set_dif[N];

    find_set_difference(a, b, N, set_dif);

    printf("The difference of set A and set B is: \n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(set_dif[i]==1)
        printf("%d ",i);
    }

    return 0;
}

void find_set_difference(int *set_a, int *set_b, int n, int *set_difference){

    int *p, *q;

    for(p=set_a; p<set_a+n; p++){
        for(q=set_b; q<set_b+n; q++){
            if(p==1 && q==0)
                set_difference = 1;
            else 
                set_difference = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance with formatting and using pointers would be helpful, as I am still new to coding and am having difficulty understanding the concepts.

Comment: `b[k]=1` will set the value 1 whatever you input before.

Comment: `set_difference` is a pointer to an array. What are you expecting `set_difference = 1;` to do? I think you want to assign to an element of the array, not the array itself.

Comment: You never set `k` before `&a[k]`. I think you meant `&k`.

Comment: What if `n` is more than `10`? Why don't you use the same size for `set_dif` as `a`?

Comment: What if the number of elements in set A is different from set B? You're only passing the size of `b` to the function. You need this to be in different variables.

Answer (score 2):

The following checks the value of the pointers:

```c
if(p==1 && q==0)
```

You want to check the pointed values.

```c
if(*p==1 && *q==0)
```

---

The following sets the value of the pointer:

```c
set_difference = 1;
```

You want to set the pointed variable.

```c
*set_difference = 1;
```

---

This answer only addresses the warnings you asked about. There are a number of other major problems, but I don't want to do your homework for you. Think about *how many different variables do you want to set.*

- You are currently setting one.
- You are currently setting it n*n times.

Answer (score 0):

you some problems in your code:

1. the value of variable `k` isn't being initialized in the loop as it's used being as an iterator, also  `a[k] = 1` doesn't make any since as this is an array not hash table, assume if `input1 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and `input2 = 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`, the way you write that line makes that **input1  is same as input2** :

   ```
   for(i=0; i<n; i++){
       scanf("%d", &a[k]);
       a[k] = 1;
   }
   ```

so you should do :

```
for(i=0, k = 0; i<n; i++, k++){
    scanf("%d", &a[k]);
}
```

---

2. using the same variable `n` for 2 different arrays can result in some errors if the user entered different sizes for the 2 different arrays

so use another variable to get the size of the second array instead of `n` that's being used for the first array

---

3. the size of the `set_dif` in line :

   ```
   int set_dif[N];
   ```

is better to be the size of the smallest array of them, but it wouldn't make any difference if its size is greater than that.

---

4. in this line :

   ```
   if(p==1 && q==0)
   ```

you are comparing address which is pointer `p` with a value which is `1`

so instead you should compare the value in that address with value `1`, so you should do:  `if(*p==1 && *q==0)`

---

5. in this line:

   ```
   set_difference = 1;
   ```

`set_difference` is a pointer to the array which means it's an address, so you can't do **address = Value**, instead you should do the:

```
     set_difference[i] = 1;
```

where `i` is an iterator

---

6. also in the line:

   ```
   if(*p==1 && *q==0)
   ```

you should compare  `if(*p!=*q)` as not to make the problem discussed in point 1
and the array called `set_dif` should be initialized with ones.

---

7. instead of:

   ```
     printf("%d ",i);
   ```

write: `printf("%d ",a[i]);` , as to achieve what are seeking with this line, you should look for something called [hash table](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/hash-table-in-c-plus-plus)

---

with all that being said, this is the full edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void find_set_difference(int *set_a, int *set_b, int n, int m, int *set_difference);

int main(void)
{
    int i, k = 0;
    int n, m;

    printf("Enter the number of elements in set A: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    int a[n];

    printf("Enter the elements in set A: \n");

    for(i=0, k = 0; i<n; i++, k++){
        scanf(" %d", &a[k]);
    }

    printf("Enter the number of elements in set B: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int b[m];

    printf("Enter the elements in set B: \n");

    for(i=0, k = 0; i<n; i++, k++){
        scanf("%d", &b[k]);
    }

    int set_dif[n];

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        set_dif[j] = 1;
    }

    find_set_difference(a, b, n, m, set_dif);

    printf("The difference of set A and set B is: \n");
    for(i=0; i< n ;i++){
        if(set_dif[i] != 0)
             printf("%d \t",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void find_set_difference(int *set_a, int *set_b, int n, int m, int *set_difference){

    int *p, *q;
    int i = 0;
    for(p = set_a; p < set_a + n; p++, i++){
        for(q = set_b; q< set_b + m ; q++){
            if(*p==*q)
                set_difference[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is some example output:

```
Enter the number of elements in set A:
5
Enter the elements in set A:
1
3
4
5
6
Enter the number of elements in set B:
5
Enter the elements in set B:
2
3
4
6
8
The difference of set A and set B is:
1       5
```